# compile and link OpenEXR emscripten multiple main function defines

Tags: emscripten, freeimage, openexr

I'm trying to compile `OpenEXR with emscripten` and link it to my program that will eventually be an `html` file.

I have no problem compiling `OpenEXR with emscripten`. The problem is when I try to link the `.bc` file with my application. I get an error that says

> "EXEC : error : Linking globals named 'main': symbol multiply
>   defined!".

I tracked this error and found out that there is a `main` function inside one of the CPP files inside OpenEXR. it's [b44ExpLogTable.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/free-image/+/71163caf89862f79f6419077cf6f0b18b7725d52/Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/b44ExpLogTable.cpp)

So I can't link my program with `OpenEXR.bc` library because I have a main function and b44ExpLogTable.cpp also has a `main` function.

I don't know how to get around that. If I try to compile `OpenEXR using MSVC++` I don't get this problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`b44ExpLogTable.cpp` is a source code generator that is only needed to generate same static arrays that are linked to the OpenEXR lib. So it actually is a program by itself that contains a `main` function.